# jQuery Navigation - need help with positioning and accordion behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

The sidebar navigation here: http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/in_the_garden needs some TLC.

There are a couple of issues that I am trying to resolve and could use some assistance:

1. The accordion action works fine but the single line item links (that do not accordion) do not link correctly to their pages. What is preventing that?
2. With an accordion open (like The Collection) if you mouse over the parent link below it Find your Zone, it highlights the entire section before it.
3. Is there a way to keep a section open while on a specific page?

here is the code:

The HTML

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu noaccordion">
<li><a class="m1" href="#">the collection</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/shrubs/">shrubs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/groundcovers_grasses/">groundcovers/<br />grasses</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/trees/">trees</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/tropicals/">tropicals</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/fall_bulbs/">fall bulbs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/spring_bulbs/">spring bulbs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/annuals/">annuals</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/perennials/">perennials</a></li>

    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="m2" href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/find_your_zone">find your zone</a></li>
<li><a class="m3" href="#">in the garden</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/care_tips/">care tips</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/color_guide/">color guide</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/common_pests/">common pests</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="m4" href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/where_to_buy">where to buy</a></li>
<li>
    <a class="m5" href="#">about us</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/history">history</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/media_room/">media room</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/events">events</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/botanical_gardens">botanical gardens</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/testimonials">testimonials</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a class="m6" href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/video/">plant videos</a></li>
<li><a class="m7" href="http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/contact_us">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Javascript:

```
function initMenus() {
    $('ul.menu ul').hide();
    $.each($('ul.menu'), function(){
        $('#' + this.id + '.expandfirst ul:first').show();
    });
    $('ul.menu li a').click(
        function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode.id;

            if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
                return false;
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                if($('#' + parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                    $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                }
                return false;
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $('#' + parent + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
                checkElement.slideDown('normal');
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function() {initMenus();});
```

The CSS:

```
ul.menu, ul.menu ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10em;
  float: left;

}

ul.menu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px; 
  color: #54301A;   
}

ul.menu li {
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #54301A;
}

ul.menu li a {
 /* background: #f8f2e3; */
  color: #000;  
  padding: 0.5em;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  background: #f8f2e3;
}

ul.menu li ul li { 
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #54301A; 
 }

ul.menu li ul li a {
  /* background: #f8f2e3; */
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

ul.menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #f8f2e3;
 /* border-left: 5px #000 solid; */
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JVwTB/

- Removed the third `if` block, and `return false;`
- Added `>` to some of your CSS rules

Comment: Hi Kei, Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly. Do you have a recommendation for keeping the accordion open when we are on a subsection link?

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVwTB/1/ I guess what you could do is have the pages you want the accordion open have some index variable, then call openAccordion(idx).

Comment: This is pretty close. It works on the first segment, but the first segment remains open if you are in the second or third segment: http://dev.southernlivingplants.com/care_tips/. Is there something I need to do to identify the other accordion elements to get them to function correctly? Thanks. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: The first segment remains open cause the openAccordion function is hardcoded with the argument 0. I was hoping from that you could figure it on your own :)  [ But since you didn't, here: http://jsfiddle.net/JY6E5/ ]

Comment: Hi Kei, brilliant. I wish I could award more credit. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the answers to your issues:

1) The `return false;` statement in the following code is preventing the normal behavior:

```
if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
            $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
            return false;
        }
```

2) Add `clear: left;` to the following CSS selector `ul.menu li`

3) Yes, this is possible using Javascript, but requires a little bit of work :)

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had a clearer answer, but it looks like your `.click()` function is consuming the click event, and not passing it on to the element itself. Usually this is done explicitly via a call to `stopPropagation()`, but since you're not doing that here, I would think the event would still trigger the href.

Maybe you could explicitly redirect the browser in your javascript near the if statement `if($('#' + parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) ...` as a workaround.